# What are the generating sets of $\mathcal{F}_t^X=\sigma(X_s , 0 \leq s \leq t) $?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, filtrations

When can $\mathcal{F}_t^X=\sigma(X_s , 0 \leq s \leq t) $ be generated by sets of the form
$F=\{X_{t_0} \in \Gamma_1\, X_{t_1} \in \Gamma_2 ,\dots, X_{t_n} \in \Gamma_n \}$ where $\Gamma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $0=t_0<t_1 <t_2 \dots <t_n=t$  ??

I mean under what regularity conditions on the stochastic process $X$ is the above true?

I suspect that right or left continuity(can't even show this) of $X$ implies the existence of such generating sets? Would this be true for any Markov Process $X$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No condition! Just take $\sigma \{X_{t_0}\in \Gamma_1,.....,X_{t_n}\in \Gamma_n\}$ and verify that this is equal to $\sigma \{X_s:0\leq s\leq t\}$ by verifying that each side is contained in the other.

Comment: One direction is obvious , any hints on how could I show the Rhs is contained in the Lhs ?

Comment: $\sigma (X_s:0\leq s \leq t)$ is the smallest sigma algebra that makes each $X_s$ measurable. Since each $X_s$ is measurable with respect to the sigma filed generated by sets of the given type ( by taking $n=1$) it follows that $\sigma (X_s:0\leq s \leq t)$ is contained in the sigma algebra generated by those sets.

Comment: Yes ofcourse . I should have thought of that . My bad !